# How can I get all transactions associated with an account using web3.js?

Tags: web3.js, javascript

Given a PublicKey, how can I view all transactions associated with said PublicKey using web3js?

Comment: Just a note, if you are trying to get any and all history for a NFT using it's `PublicKey` -- some programs/sites don't include it correctly n the transaction and thus you won't be able to get every single event that ever took place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution would be to call `getSignaturesForAddress` (https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress). This returns an array of 1000 signatures backwards in time from the provided/most recent confirmed block so if you have more than 1000 transactions in the history for your pubkey you'll need to call this in a loop. It takes an optional `SignaturesForAddressOptions` which contains `before`, you'll want to pass in the oldest signature from the last response.

Once you have all of your signatures, you can use `getTransactions` or `getParsedTransactions` (https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransactions) to get the transactions associated with your signatures.

Comment: is the getParsedTransactions meant to provide the from and to address as well? So far no luck

Comment: yes, getParsedTransactions should provide both to & from addresses.

Answer (score -1):

there are two rpc endpoints involved here:

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction